# Angular 2 simple directive to toggle class

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have structure in html like this

```html
<div class="col-8">
    text
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    text
</div>
```

What I need is to create simple directive in my **app.component.ts**, that will on click on some element toggle and ad class **col-12**, than html will look like this

```html
<div class="col-8 col-12">
    text
</div>
<div class="col-4 col-12">
    text
</div>
```

I am sorry i dont have nothing in code right now, but i need help to get started

Comment: Have any idea about [ngClass](https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference#ng-class) ?

Comment: Yes but how to get that element and toggle class in directive?

Answer (score 2):

Use HostBinding decorators to bind property

**customDirective.ts**

```
import { Directive,HostBinding,HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDynamicClass]'
})
export class DynamicClassDirective {

@HostBinding('class.col-12') isActive=false;

  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('click',['$event']) onClick(){
    console.log('clicked');
    this.isActive=!this.isActive;
  }

}
```

**component.ts**

```
<button class="col-2" appDynamicClass>
  Click
</button>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/hostbinfing

Answer (score -1):

Why you need a directive, we can achieve this using ngClass attribute.

```
<div class="col-8" (click)="handleClick()" [ngClass]="{'col-12' : icClick}">
    text
</div>
<div class="col-4" (click)="handleClick()" [ngClass]="{'col-12' : icClick}">
    text
</div>
```

**Component**

```
icClick = false;
handleClick(){
   this.icClick = !this.icClick;
}
```

Comment: I need directive, because on some other place i will have and icon that will handle that, maybe on several places also

Comment: With a Directive you can generalize such behaviours. Your solution does it on only one place.